# Android studio emulator uses heaps of cpu?

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, cpu, cpu-usage

I'm making an application for android through android studio and **when I run it on my physical phone it has no issues using up to 15% CPU** maximum but **when I ran it on a Nexus 5 emulator it goes up to 100% CPU just when pressing a button that doesn't even have an onclick, the button just has the default button press animation and that's it..** Then when pressing the button that takes the app to the activity where my game is played it just crashes. Any ideas on how to fix this issue is much appreciated.

The Emulator has the same firmware, same resolution, x86 CPU/ABI and 1GB "size on disk".

**LogCat Error:**

```
Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 5760012 byte allocation with 3153988 free bytes and 3MB until OOM"
```